# Regex: Alternators order issue

Tags: python, regex, regex-alternation

When using [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) in regex, we should include items in the alternators in order to avoid being affected by eagerness of the engine.

Then if having a list such as `co,co.,co-op,association,assoc` we should prefer to include them in order to get the most precise match. Then, this should be changed to `association,assoc,co-op,co.,co`.

I have a basic regex pattern to split a word in two if hyphen or slash is included, so I get just the part before the hyphen or slash:

```
(.*(?<!\w)(CO-OP|CO|CO.)(?!\w).*)[-/](\s*\w+.*)
```

However, this regex is breaking incorrectly when providing `ABC CO-OP ELEMENTARY SCHOOL`. This string is becoming just `ABC CO`. However, if I remove CO from the alternators, the string is returned in its original form `ABC CO-OP ELEMENTARY SCHOOL` which is correct. In addition, the string `ARMSTRONG CO-OP ELEMENTARY SCHOOL / ECOLE PRIMAIRE ARMSTRONG COOPERATIVE` should be broken to become `ARMSTRONG CO-OP ELEMENTARY SCHOOL` without the string after slash.

Why `CO` is matched in the alternators and used to break the string?

Comment: `CO.` should be `CO[.]` or `CO\.` but that's not your current issue. You could use control verbs to skip the `co,co.,co-op` matches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that your regex *requires* there to be a `-` or a `\` in the string, so it is forcing `ABC CO-OP ELEMENTARY SCHOOL` to split on the `-` in `CO-OP`. If you:

1. make the second part of the regex optional;
2. change the `.*` at the end of the first group to be lazy (`.*?`); and
3. add start and end-of-string anchors

you will get the results you want:

```
^(.*(?<!\w)(?:CO-OP|CO|CO\.)(?!\w).*?)(?:[-/](\s*\w+.*))?$
```

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/TrVasd/3)

Note also that the `.` in `CO.` should be escaped.